# How to sort by column and break ties randomly

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I have a tab-delimited file with three columns like this:

```
joe W 4
bob A 1
ana F 1
roy J 3
sam S 0
don R 2
tim L 0
cyb M 0
```

I want to sort this file by decreasing values in the third column, but to break ties I do not want to use some other column to do so (i.e. not use the first column to sort rows with the same entry in the third column).

Instead, I want rows with the same third column entries to either preserve the original order, or be sorted randomly.

Is there a way to do this using the sort command in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -k3 -r -s file
```

This should give you the required output. 
-k3 denotes the 3rd column and -r will sort in decreasing order and -s will disable the breaking of ties using other options.

Comment: -s is the exact option I was looking for. Thanks!